# opening another window on press of enter button in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have on large grid of data about 25000 rows. [Windows Application]

In that i am trying to implement functionality like, when i press enter key i can open new window. In that new window i am showing data for the record for which i pressed enter button in terms of text boxes and labels. But unfortunately i did not found any relative event for that. when i press enter button active selected row moves to the next record.

I also want to know if there is any functionality such that when i load the window[Grid] by default first record should get selected.

I have tried different events such as

```
 private void gvTradeFile_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            splitPopUp objSplit = new splitPopUp();
            objSplit.Show();
        }
```

Not Worked.

```
private void gvTradeFile_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            splitPopUp objSplit = new splitPopUp();
            objSplit.Show();
        }
```

This also not worked.

I refered http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6a73013f-4440-4d45-a322-63c4cae1bb39/ this link but got nothing out of it.

Is there any idea related to implementing this functionality?

Comment: `gvTradeFile_RowEnter` is different event. What do you mean by `Enter` Button? Is it a button control? Or the Enter key on keyboard?

Comment: Enter key on keyboard @FreddieFabregas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle grid's [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event:

```
private void gvTradeFile_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        var row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow; // retreive the current row
        // show the form
        // ...
    }
}
```

The [`Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) event occurs when keyboard focus *enters* into the grid, and [`RowEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter.aspx) event occurs when a row receives input focus. These events have no relation to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: what values comes in var row?

Comment: got the expected result. Thank You.

Comment: `row` is of type [`DataGridViewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.aspx). If you have bound data grid to a data source, you can use [`DataBoundItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx) property to retrives the row values.

Comment: what i can do if i directly want to close window on press of escape button?[Not any relation with grid now] @MD.Unicorn

Comment: @Freelancer It is better to ask another question for this, or better than that, google it! But here is your answer: Put a button on the form (`btnClose`) and set its `DialogResult` property to `Cancel`. Then select your form and change the `CancelButton` to `btnCancel` (your new button).